# Does Firebase support AdServices.framework?

Tags: ios, firebase, tracking

We want to track Apple Ad Search campaigns (installations and post install actions) using Firebase/Google Analytics. Prior iOS 14.5, we just needed to add the iAd.framework. But after iOS 14.5, Apple says that we need to use the new AdServices.framework.
Does anybody know if Firebase supports this framework?
We understand that with this framework is not necessary to ask for the users permission to track basic campaigns like Apple Ad Search, but maybe we are wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Version 10.6.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#version_1060_-_february_28_2023) added support for Apple AdServices to measure Apple Search Ads campaign when the framework is integrated.

Ref: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7860

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, AdServices framework will enable developers to track Apple Search Ads campaigns regardless of the users' ATT permission status. However, I cannot track my ASA campaigns on Google Analytics. Still looking into that problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).